# Failed to get from node cache

Tags: caching, cassandra, kong

In Kong getting below errors.

- `failed to get from node cache: [cassandra error] all hosts tried for query failed. 1.2.3.4: host still considered down, context: ssl_certificate_by_lua, client: 1.2.3.5, server: 0.0.0.0:443.
  SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408A179:SSL routines:Ssl3_get_client_hello:cert cb error) while SSL handshaking`
- `load_plugin_configuration(): failed to get from node cache: callback threw an error: [cassandra error] [Unavailable exception] Cannot achieve consistency level ALL`

This error is frequent and seems to be related to caching. Can some body explain what is the root cause of this error and how to avoid this error.
Using Kong CE 0.13, Cassandra 3.11.1

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like you've specified a client consistency level of ALL. In that scenario you will achieve the highest level of consistency (all nodes must acknowledge a write/read in order to "move on") at the sacrifice of availability. If the client consistency level is ALL, because all nodes must acknowledge the request, no nodes for the data being retrieved can be unavailable. If such a scenario occurs, you receive an error similar to what you see above. Unless I'm misunderstanding the error message above, according to your output, it seems that at least one node is down causing your query to fail.

Setting the client consistency level to ALL is a bit extreme and generally not best practice in cassandra (due to what you're noticing above). You do want to allow for, in most cases, some fault tolerance. In most cases, a client consistency level of QUORUM or LOCAL_QUORUM is a decent balance of "comfortable" consistency, yet allowing node(s) to be unavailable without failure. These settings are completely client driven - meaning the client has control (at the connection level or even at a per-statement level) of their consistency/fault tolerance requirements (i.e. check your software to see how you can adjust the client consistency level, if desired).

-Jim

Comment: is the same root cause(all nodes must acknowledge a write/read in order to "move on") applicable for "failed to get from node cache" error.

Comment: I believe those are related - but could be wrong. Don't know much about the application you referenced. My guess is the function from the app's perspective is: "getting node from cache", which then queries cassandra to get that information. Just a hunch though. The "cannot achieve consistency ALL" is definitely related to the consistency settings I mentioned above.